# Audit trail of changes to questions

Tags: discussion

A question was asked that requested a a certain style of answer which I attempted because it exposed the difficulties in a way that interested me.  Subsequently the question was edited and the constraint removed.  My effort was wasted and the question became bog standard.  Is there, or should there be an audit trail for changes to answers?

Answer (score 2):

You can see a full edit history of a question and of its answers.  Doing anything more would needlessly increase the complexity of the site

Generally Speaking, We prefer that question askers not *fundamentially* change their questions in a way that can invalidate existing answers.

On the flip side, If someone asks an awkward question, it's usually best to get clarifications in the comments first than to post an answer that you're unsure about.

Comment: 1. I was unable to find an edit history.  I did look.
2. There is no requirement that edits be made to Qs only by the asker.

Comment: @Aethelbald If a question has been edited, you should see the time it was edited.  [Clicking on that time](https://imgur.com/Ylcx1pO) Should bring you to the edit history.

Comment: @Aethelbald take note, that if you make edits quickly enough, it will either be merged into the base question, or into the previous revision.  This is to prevent a large number of incremental edits from polluting the edit history.  I think the threshold is 5 minutes.